# Joomla 3.1 getUserStateFromRequest, will it return an array?

Tags: arrays, joomla, return, state

Short and sweet - can `getUserStateFromRequest` return an array? The API documentation appears to be incomplete?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Joomla documentation if still quite limited but looking at the source of the JApplication:: in Joomla 2.5

```
public function getUserStateFromRequest($key, $request, $default = null, $type = 'none')
{
    $cur_state = $this->getUserState($key, $default);
    $new_state = JRequest::getVar($request, null, 'default', $type);

    // Save the new value only if it was set in this request.
    if ($new_state !== null)
    {
        $this->setUserState($key, $new_state);
    }
    else
    {
        $new_state = $cur_state;
    }

    return $new_state;
}
```

The answer is YES it can if you set it with

```
JRequest::setVar('var1', array(1,2,3), 'default');

JFactory::getApplication->setUserState('var1', array(123));
```

or just pass it with the request

```
$_GET['var1'] = array(1,2,3);
$_POST['var1'] = array(1,2,3);
```